# Sharing page across websites in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, multi-tenant

Here at our company we are trying to figure out how to create one single page and share it across domains in ASP.NET.

We would like to create a simple "cart" page that is the same for all of our clients websites, so that we can include the page from a central location (such as `http://ourwebsite.com/thecart.aspx`) without duplicating code, and still be able to apply the CSS styles and branding for each client to the page.

How can we share a single page across websites in ASP.NET?

Each of our client's websites are on a different domain, and in some cases may also be on different servers as well.

Comment: if you're hosting on the same box you can use virtual directories to point to the same place

Comment: Well like I said above, in some cases we won't be hosting the sites on the same server, so we couldn't rely on Virtual Directories to share the page between sites.

Comment: wow.. I'm a space cadet. Sorry I totally missed the "servers part"

Comment: I'm not sure you could "include" the page without using iframes. You could allow a post to your `thecart` page but you'd still have to code a front end for it.

Comment: OK, and I'm sure that using a Web Service to host the page itself and return the page HTML isn't an option either, correct?

Comment: I almost said something about that but it didn't smell right. You could put `thecart` out there then use a server side script to go download the html and spit it out on your page.

Comment: So what you're saying is...I could create a webservice that returns the HTML for the page, then simply "include" it in my client's website?

Comment: a server would host the page and render it, that you would comsume yes. However I think IrishChieftain is heading a better direction. You could look at creating a UC or dll or something

Comment: Hmm, turns out that using a DLL would not be an options, since I would actually need to import the page into an ASP or PHP site as well. What could I do in this case, then?

Comment: I think at this point your best bet is going to be to host the page somewhere and use whatever your server side code is to scrape the page

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is manage one page and have it automatically update the other pages on your client's sites, ideally the same thing as "sharing a resource" no?  For that you don't necessarily need to "share" a page, you need an easy process for multiple site deployment of just the single page, errr....I think?  In any case, without loading the page via an iframe, or creating a central spot like "cart.somedomain.net" and then pushing the info back and fourth (I assume you'll have shopping cart items), you'd need a way to automate the publish of the page on different sites.

Even if you were to make the "cart" page it's own solution and then just include it in the individual sites, you'd still have the deployment issue.  I think you have a few options, some of them previously mentioned:

1. Create an iframe that loads the page from an external source.
2. Create a central location for all the domains to push information to for their checkout process (store.somedomain.net or somdomain.net/cart.aspx) and handle it accordingly.
3. Create an application or script that automates the deployment of the updated resource to multiple sites (I don't know of a tool that does this or I would offer up the name to you, I apologize).

Anyway, I hope that helps, best of luck.

Comment: Very helpful ideas, thanks. I'm leaning towards something like option #2, where this page will push to one central location from any domain. The complications now are actually preserving session state and using AJAX across domains.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from and create the page as just another server control in a custom library. You'll of course have it in source control.

In fact, it doesn't need to be a "page", rather a custom server shopping cart control.

Comment: OK interesting. So in theory, would this control be able to communicate using Session variables and AJAX as well??

Comment: Each session is unique on each Web server, right? If you need session it's there for you as a regular custom control. The only thing you need to watch out for is source control versioning if the code is changed on one and not pushed out to the other instances.

Comment: What if I create a DLL containing the control and reference it in all the client's websites?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. You'll be deploying the DLL from the custom library. Beauty of it is that it will scale should you ever want too upgrade the code or add to it over time.